# Angular2 reactive form default input value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I've got following code that initialize form in my component:

```
let editMode: boolean = !!this.template.templateId;

this.editTemplateForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  templateId: {value: editMode ? this.template.templateId : '', validators: [Validators.required, this.templateIdValidator]},
  dataStorageTime: {value: editMode ? this.template.dataStorageTime : this.globalParameter.dataStorageTime, Validators.required, Validators.pattern("[0-9]+")]});
```

Value of variable
`this.template.templateId` is undefined, so `editMode` is false. For `dataStorageTime` correct default value is set in linked input in form. Hovewer, for templateId input is set to "[object Object]" instead of empty string.

I'm using angular2 final realease.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution to my problem:

```
this.editTemplateForm = this.formBuilder.group({
templateId: [editMode ? this.template.templateId : '', [Validators.required, this.templateIdValidator]],
dataStorageTime: [editMode ? this.template.dataStorageTime : this.globalParameter.dataStorageTime, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("[0-9]+")]]
});
```

Comment: Upped your answer @mdziob, I've been banging my head for the regex pattern and tried a bunch of things, but never tried adding `+` in the pattern! Now my code works :D